Difference Between Confidence Bands and Confidence Intervals
I've read other answers on this stackexchange for this topic, but I have a few questions I would like clarified:
Confidence bands are usually visualized as the connected lines ('bands') formed from confidence intervals throughout the regression. This leads me to believe (possibly incorrectly) that the confidence band is simply the 'family' of confidence intervals throughout the entirety of the regression (i.e. the lines which envelope our regressed lines with confidence $1-\alpha$ %)
My gripe (which leads me to confusion about my above deduction), is that the formula to compute a confidence band uses the Working-Hotelling Constant, which results in a wider interval than the confidence interval at a given point (for example in SLR):
$
\begin{align}
C.B = \hat y_{i} \pm W \cdot se(\hat y_{i})
\end{align}
$
at the $x$ value associated with the observation $i$
So is my conclusion about the confidence bands incorrect? What is their relation with confidence intervals and why then do we use the $F$ distribution rather than the $t$ distribution? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

A "regressed line" is determined by, and determines, two parameters.  Consequently the confidence bands are a geometric representation of a confidence ellipse for the ordered tuple of those parameters.
